# UIButton not showing when UIScrollView showing on ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, optimization, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a `UIViewController` that is attached to a class, Swift code below. The code basically adds to the View Controller a `UIScrollView` with an image.

I am wanting to add a `UIButton` to the `ViewController` which I could do through code, however in this case, I want to add the `UIButton` to the `ViewController` using the Storyboard.

When I add a `UIButton` and then run my project, the `UIButton` is not visible, only the `UIScrollView` is visible.

**Question:**

***What is going on, why is the `UIButton` not visible? How can I add a `UIButton` (to the Storyboard) and ensure that it is visible and in front of the `UIScrollView` (that is created programatically) when I run the project?***

---

```
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.png"))

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: view.bounds)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        scrollView.contentSize = imageView.bounds.size
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]

        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 1000, y: 450)

        scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.delegate = self
        setZoomScale()
        setupGestureRecognizer()
    }

    func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        setZoomScale()
    }

    func setZoomScale() {
        let imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size
        let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
        let widthScale = scrollViewSize.width / imageViewSize.width
        let heightScale = scrollViewSize.height / imageViewSize.height

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
        scrollView.zoomScale = 1.0
    }

    func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let imageViewSize = imageView.frame.size
        let scrollViewSize = scrollView.bounds.size
        let verticalPadding = imageViewSize.height < scrollViewSize.height ? (scrollViewSize.height - imageViewSize.height) / 2 : 0
        let horizontalPadding = imageViewSize.width < scrollViewSize.width ? (scrollViewSize.width - imageViewSize.width) / 2 : 0

        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalPadding, left: horizontalPadding, bottom: verticalPadding, right: horizontalPadding)
    }

    func setupGestureRecognizer() {
        let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleDoubleTap:")
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)
    }

    func handleDoubleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if (scrollView.zoomScale > scrollView.minimumZoomScale) {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.minimumZoomScale, animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(scrollView.maximumZoomScale, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the button constraints properly checking that you don't have any sort of conflicts?

Comment: Yes, I set the width, height, and centered it, no conflicts. When I run the project, and zoom out the `UIScrollView`, I can see the `UIButton`, but it is behind the `UIScrollView` instead of being in front.

Answer (score 2):

Your scrollview is blocking the UIButton on z axis, please use

`- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index;`

to insert scrollview below UIButton

Swift:

```
func insertSubview(view: UIView, atIndex index: Int) {
}
```

Answer:

Instead of this line `view.addSubview(scrollView)`, you need to do `self.view.insertSubview(scrollView, atIndex: 0)` and make sure `UIButton` is above the `scrollView`.

Comment: The `UIButton` is created on the Storyboard and the `UIScrollView` is created in code. I've copied the above code, in Swift, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a specific place it should be placed?

Comment: Instead of this line   view.addSubview(scrollView), you need to do self.view.insertSubview(scrollView, atIndex: 0) and make sure UIButton is above the scrollView.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write:

```
self.view.insertSubview(scrollview, belowSubview: button)
```